# Read only digit from OTP SMS in Android Studio

Tags: android, sms, digit, one-time-password

I am trying to read OTP from SMS in android. I am able to receive entire message. But, I need only OTP that is only digit from SMS.

Please suggest any solution for that.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
smsString = smsString.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

it will remove non-digits from `smsString`

Answer (score 1):

When entire sms fetched use this method to get OTP:

```
                    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\\d{4})" );
                    final Matcher m = p.matcher(messages[0].getMessageBody());
                    if ( m.find() ) {
                        Log.e("SMSotp", String.valueOf(m.group()));
                    }
                    String[] singleCHAR= m.group().split("(?!^)");
```

Here, if your OTP is n digit then use, (\d{n}) in Pattern compile